# Typeorm many-to-one / one-to-many resulting in unexpected results

Tags: typeorm

I am new to Typeorm but I feel like I have a fairly simple example that is resulting in some unexpected results. Lets say I have a Client. Each Client can have many ClientUsers. Each ClientUser can have only one Client.

Example:

Client Schema:

```
module.exports = new EntitySchema({
    name: "Client",
    target: Client,
    columns: {
        id: {
            primary: true,
            type: "uuid",
            generated: "uuid"
        },
        name: {
            type: "varchar"
        },
        telephone: {
          type: "varchar"
        },
        email: {
            type: "varchar"
        }
    },
    relations: {
        client_users: {
            target: "ClientUser",
            type: "one-to-many",
            cascade: true
        }
    }
});
```

ClientUser Schema:

```
module.exports = new EntitySchema({
    name: "ClientUser",
    target: ClientUser,
    columns: {
        id: {
            primary: true,
            type: "uuid",
            generated: "uuid"
        },
        first_name: {
            type: "varchar"
        },
        last_name: {
            type: "varchar"
        },
        title: {
            type: "varchar"
        },
        email: {
            type: "varchar"
        },
        username: {
            type: "varchar"
        },
        password: {
            type: "varchar"
        }
    },
    relations: {
        client: {
            target: "Client",
            type: "many-to-one",
            joinColumn: true,
            cascade: true
        }
    }
});
```

This result in the ClientUser table having a column called `clientid`, which is always null. If I change ClientUser schema relation to the following (update client to client_id):

```
    relations: {
        client_id: {
            target: "Client",
            type: "many-to-one",
            joinColumn: true,
            cascade: true
        }
    }
```

I get a column named `clientIdId` but the column is correctly populated with the related client id.

I am obviously doing something really simply wrong here but I've been looking at it so long, it escapes me. Please help me understand how I can have a logical column name, that gets populated as expected.